# How to use Code First approach for single table in existing database which already has many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

**Scenario** : I have an existing database, say "DemoDB". It has many tables already there. These tables are used in my existing application using `LINQ` to `SQL` or ADO.Net technology. Now I have a requirement where I have to add a new table "NewTable" in DemoDB and do the CRUD operation on that. I want to use "Code First Approach" for simplicity. I have defined new class for "NewTable" in my application.

**Problem** : When I execute my application it removes all the existing tables for my database. I do not want to create classes for existing tables. Only NewTable is remaining there in my database.

Please suggest if there is any cleaner and simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this would work, but you can research more on this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null) in the Global.ASAX.
```

Good Luck !!